# Assigning numbers to text in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an input cell A1 that can be filled by any combinations of A, B, C, D. I have assigned scores to them such that A=5, B=3, C=3 and D=1. How do I create a rule such that my output cell returns the lowest of any of the individual scores, e.g. input cell has A, B, C, D therefore output cell should be 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If A=5, B=3, C=3 and D=1

1] To return the lowest of any of the individual scores

In `B1`, copied down :

```
=LOOKUP(1,-FIND({"A";"C";"B";"D"},A1),{5;3;3;1})
```

[image]

2] To return the highest of any of the individual scores

In `B1`, copied down :

=LOOKUP(1,-FIND({"D";"B";"C";"A"},A1),{1;3;3;5})

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The below formula works for the provided condition (A1 = "A,B,C,D"; Result = 1). You will have to modify the same according to your requirement.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("D",A1)),1,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("C",A1)),3,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("B",A1)),3,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("A",A1)),5,""))))
```

Comment: thanks! How should I amend the formula if I want the cell to return the highest of the individual scores instead?

Comment: Just reverse the order in Search function. Instead of starting with "D", Start with 
"A"